# How to order, set limits and breaks in barplot in R Studio?

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

Here is what I have so far. I have to get my graph (in the picture) to look like the bottom picture! How can I get the order of the countries, title, and color like the picture?

- Have the countries and their corresponding data go in order of (New Zeland, Taiwan, Australia, Iceland, United Kingdom, Canada, Vietnam, Italy, India, Japan, Germany, United States, Estonia, Indonesia, Philippines, South Africa, Serbia, Argentina, Tunisia, Ecuador) because New Zeland has the highest number and Ecuador has the lowest number.
- Change the color of each bar
- Add title

ANY SPECIFIC CODE YOU CAN PROVIDE AS IT RELATES TO MY DATASET WILL BE MUCH APPRECIATED!

View project_data_1 Data Set

```
View(ProjectData_1)
```

**Install and Load Packages**

```
library(ggplot2)
library(sjstats)
library(car)
library(pwr)
```

**Labeling Variables**

```
Countries <- ProjectData_1$Entity
TestPerCase <- ProjectData_1$cumulative_tests_per_case
```

**Create New DataFrame**

```
Countries <- c("New Zeland", "Taiwan", "Australia", "Iceland", "United Kingdom", "Canada", "Vietnam", "Italy",
               "India", "Japan", "Germany", "United States", "Estonia", "Indonesia","Philippines", "South Afria", "Serbia",
               "Argentina", "Tunisia", "Ecuador")
```

```
TestPerCase <- c(500, 250, 250, 41.7, 32.3, 27, 26.3, 23.8, 18.5, 15.4, 14.7, 13.7, 10.5, 8.7, 8.1, 6.5, 5.4, 4.9, 4.4, 4.6)
```

```
NewProjectData1 <-data.frame(Countries, TestPerCase)
print(NewProjectData1)
```

**Create Bar Graph**

```
Data1BarGraph <- ggplot (NewProjectData1, aes(x=Countries, y=TestPerCase)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")
Data1BarGraph + coord_flip()
```

[I have to get my graph (the top one) to look like the bottom graph-->](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KwYJC.png)

Comment: You have "TestPerCase" defined as a vector of character strings.  Remove the quotes.  `TestPerCase <- c(500, 250, 250,...)`

Comment: @Dave2e Wow... I totally feel like an idiot. How did I not notice this... that's what I get for working on this at 3 AM... THANK YOU for noticing this!

Comment: @Dave2e I have tried looking at that question but nothing seems to be working.. would you be able to provide me an example to get started? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As per reference, [Order Bars in ggplot2 bar graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5208679/order-bars-in-ggplot2-bar-graph), to order the country values other than alphabetical, one needs to convert into factors, specifying the order.

```
Countries <- c("New Zeland", "Taiwan", "Australia", "Iceland", "United Kingdom", "Canada", "Vietnam", "Italy",
               "India", "Japan", "Germany", "United States", "Estonia", "Indonesia","Philippines", "South Afria", "Serbia",
               "Argentina", "Tunisia", "Ecuador")
TestPerCase <- c(500, 250, 250, 41.7, 32.3, 27, 26.3, 23.8, 18.5, 15.4, 14.7, 13.7, 10.5, 8.7, 8.1, 6.5, 5.4, 4.9, 4.4, 4.6)

#create dataframe
NewProjectData1 <-data.frame(Countries, TestPerCase)

#Convert Countries into a factors, ordered by TestPerCase value
NewProjectData1$Countries <- factor(NewProjectData1$Countries, 
                                    levels= NewProjectData1$Countries[order(NewProjectData1$TestPerCase)])

#Plot
#geom_col instead of geom_bar, avoids the extra 'stat = "identity"'
Data1BarGraph <- ggplot(NewProjectData1, aes(x=Countries, y=TestPerCase, fill=Countries)) +
   geom_col() +  
   coord_flip() +
   labs(title = "TestperCase vs Country")

Data1BarGraph
```

Comment: Thank you so much! How would I be able to add a title for my graph?

Comment: @vanaynay25 did this answer your question?